# Can scopes be assigned to oauth clients?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I'm developing a multi tenant service that will serve multiple clients. Those clients are on-premise applications. I'm also going to create client identities in the authorization service and then distribute those to my clients. Since this is a machine to machine communication I'm going to use **client_credentials** oauth flow. My clients should have different authorization scopes. Does oauth allow assigning scopes to clients at the authorization service? Or do I need to use another protocol like openid?

Answer (score 0):

**SCOPES**

OAuth allows you to assign different scopes to different clients, though if clients all access the same data this is not recommended and is a form of `scope explosion`.

[Scopes](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) represent an area of data and what you are allowed to do with that data, eg `orders_write`. They are fixed at design time.

**AUTHORIZATION DESIGN**

OAuth is primarily about protecting data, and how you authorize often depends on the client application. Eg do you need to know who the user is when authorizing? If so then client credentials flow is not right. If clients are APIs that manage their own user level authorization, it is fine.

**CLAIMS**

Most real world authorization is done using [claims](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/). Eg in multi-tenant setups you would include a `tenant_id` claim in the access token. Not all systems support issuing custom claims like this, in which case you need a mapping table from the `client_id` to tenant_id. This will enable you to authorize per client while also using scopes in the preferred way.